# Не выбираются значения выпадающего меню select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, select2

Использую плагин select2 для поиска городов которые с сервера забирает ajax, дальше через плагин вывожу в  форму на странице примерно такого содержания

```
<select class="form-control from" id="from"></select>
```

таким скриптом добавляю в форму значения

```
$(".from").select2({
        language: 'ru',
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        placeholder: "выберите город",
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "script.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    to: 'searchCity'
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        templateResult: formatRepo,
        templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
    });

    function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
      return repo.lable || repo.text;
    }
    function formatRepo (repo) {
      if (repo.loading) return repo.text;

      var markup = "<option value='"+ repo.code +"'>"+repo.name+"</option>";
      return markup;
    }
```

При поиске значения заполняют выпадающие меню, но при нажатии на любой элемент списка ничего не происходит, форма никак не реагирует, что я делаю не так?

upd: скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выпадающие значения выбрать невозможно

upd2:
вот так выглядит ответ сервера

```
[{"label":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430, \u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f (MOW)","code":"MOW","name":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430"},{"label":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0440, \u0411\u043e\u0441\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0438 \u0413\u0435\u0440\u0446\u0435\u0433\u043e\u0432\u0438\u043d\u0430 (OMO)","code":"OMO","name":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0440"},{"label":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u044c\u043e\u0435\u043d, \u041d\u043e\u0440\u0432\u0435\u0433\u0438\u044f (MJF)","code":"MJF","name":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u044c\u043e\u0435\u043d"},{"label":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u0441\u043e\u0440\u043e, \u0420\u0438\u0443-\u0413\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0438-\u0434\u0443-\u041d\u043e\u0440\u0442\u0438, \u0411\u0440\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043b\u0438\u044f (MVF)","code":"MVF","name":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u0441\u043e\u0440\u043e"},{"label":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0435\u0440\u0430, \u041a\u043e\u043b\u0443\u043c\u0431\u0438\u044f (MQR)","code":"MQR","name":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0435\u0440\u0430"}]
```

Comment: А список совсем не открывается, или открывается а опции не получается выбирать?

Comment: открывается список, но значения не выбираются

Comment: @user193361 не могли бы вы уточнить, не понимаю, что значит "не выбираются"? Клик по элементу выпадающего списка не работает и ничего не происходит (если да - пробовали клавиатурой?)? Или элемент выбирается, но значение select не меняется? Можете добавит скриншот итогового селекта в развернутом виде?

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: @user193361 по элементам кликаете и ничего не происходит, верно? Даже список не сворачивается? А в консоли ошибок нет?

Comment: да именно так, ошибок в консоли нету

Comment: @user193361 последнее безумное предположение - у вас выпадающий список не перекрыт сверху прозрачным блоком? При наведении на элементы списка hover как-то проявляется? Если да - дело не в этом.

Comment: да кстати, hover никак не проявляется. Если в примерах на сайте плагина навести мышку на элемент появляется hover, то у меня этого нету

Comment: @ИванПшеницын возможно дело в пост обработке принятых данных? Пробовал без нее, но в консоль выводилась ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел ответ на собственный вопрос: добавил в выборке mysql вывод id каждого элемента, и выпадающее меню заработало как нужно, но осталься вопрос для чего это нужно? почему без id не прокатывает?

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    repo.selected = true;
    return repo.lable || repo.text;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ваш ответ объяснениями, что и как работает